# Togglemenu closed inside navbar angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating some sidebar menu using angular 2.

This is what i have for now

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="toggleMenu()" class="hamburger">
  <span>toggle menu</span>
</button>

<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<app-menu [@slideInOut]="menuState"></app-menu>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
      })),
      state('out', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)'
      })),
      transition('in => out', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('out => in', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  menuState:string = 'out';

  toggleMenu() {
    // 1-line if statement that toggles the value:
    this.menuState = this.menuState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
  }
}
```

**menu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<button (click)="toggleMenu()" class="hamburger">
      <span>toggle menu</span>
    </button>
    <ul>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
```

This iway i am toggle right side menu, but only problem i have is that inside menu componenet html i also have toggle that does not work, entire is made from this link
https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-animate-creating-sliding-side-navigation

What i need is to close the menu inside menu component, any idea how to do that??

Comment: If you want to trigger the toggleMenu function, then you need to put it inside menu.component.ts

Comment: I have tried nothing happens

Comment: You also have to remove the button from the app.component.html

Comment: Otherwise you need to use an event emitter if want to emit some data to app component

Comment: Can you write solution?

Comment: DGarvanski wrote the solution i was thinking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit an event from the `app-menu` component.
You need to create an `EventEmitter` in  `MenuComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() onMenuToggle = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    toggleMenu() {
      this.onMenuToggle.emit(null) //Emit an event here
    }
}
```

Then you need to use the emitted event in your template:

```
<app-menu [@slideInOut]="menuState" (onMenuToggle)="toggleMenu()"></app-menu>
```